# How do i know the latest version of dart environment sdk

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following image from `pubspec.yaml` file and I am confused about these versions in the red circle.

How to know what is the latest versions of these release numbers ..

[image]

Comment: The first above circle is the version for your project and below is the the flutter env. version. To get the latest use `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

The top circle is the version for your current project

The second circle is the flutter version

1. Open your flutter project root directory in Command Prompt or Terminal type `

flutter --version command

to check your version

Answer (score 1):

The first one is your application version with a build number on it

```
version: 1.0.0 + 1
         app version + build version
```

The second one is your dart version with a min-max set version

```
SDK: '>=2.15 <3.0.0'
```

To get the current version of dart installed

```
dart --version
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my Flutter global version, I create a new project and see what is the latest SDK version in `pubspec.yaml`.
That's how I keep my environment up to date on old projects.